# ¿Como capturar parametros enviado por el metodo GET?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Este es la forma que empleo pero no me llega a capturar el párametro en la controladora entra en el else pero no captura :

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.method=='POST':
            print "rrr" * 99
        else:
            a=request.GET['user']
            print('aa'*20)
            print a
```

Comment: podrías agregar como realizas el GET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
a = request.GET.get('user')
```

Comment: cual sería la diferencia con request.GET['user'] ? me parece que el problema es que no existe en realidad ese parámetro. =(

Comment: Tienes que verificar que si se este enviando desde el frontend, la diferencia es que el `request.GET.get('user', '')` es mas seguro ya que puedes poner un valor por default en caso de que llegue vacío.

Comment: Al parecer no me esta enviando proque probe esta via con el parametro por default 'None' y me lo devolvio.gracias

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de obtener la variable usando Django es correcta,

```
a = request.GET['user']
print a
```

me parece que el parámetro no se llama en realidad "user".

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que estás tratando de hacer es obtener el usuario que está logueado, este siempre está disponible en el `request`, para obtenerlo solo tienes que hacer esto:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    # ...
```